# Where do I obtain the Rocketfish RF-AFHD35 Card Reader driver?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, drivers

I've got a RocketFish SATA enclosure, model number RF-AHD35.  It has a card reader on it.  Windows doesn't see the card reader.  I figure it's a driver problem.  But, I don't have the CD that came with it anymore, nor is it available from their site.  As a matter of fact, their site looks like my 8 year old made it.

Does anyone have access to this driver?

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Before this gets moved to Super User (which is where it belongs), I would suggest [www.driverguide.com](http://www.driverguide.com) - I've been using them since the late 1990s and they're pretty good, just be careful about which download link you click because the real ones can sometimes be hidden among fake advertisements pretending to be the real links.

Answer (score 1):

RocketFish is a company that rebrands a products made by companies that no one's ever heard of. That way Best Buy (who owns RocketFish) can sell products that look like they are backed by a large company, but still don't look like the 'Store Brand'.

It might be possible to find out what the product or model number originally was and get drivers from the actual manufacturer, though the actual manufacturer's webpage is likely in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

The [product page](http://www.rocketfishproducts.com/pc-117-3-rocketfish-hard-drive-enclosure-kit-for-35-sata-hard-drives.aspx) doesn't list a CD as being included in the package, which makes me suspect that it's not so much a driver problem as a defective unit.  Have you successfully used the card reader on a different computer?